# Executing a expressions against a record

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to make a generic function to process a record(List, IEnumerable, etc) with other parameter Expressions.

```
static SelectList MyFunction<TModel, TValue, TText>(IEnumerable<TModel> records, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> val, Expression<Func<TModel, TText>> text)
```

Processing this by parsing using MemberExpression and reflection is not that hard:

```
MyFunction(records, e => e.Id, e.Name)
```

But when using a little bit complicated statements, the actual implementation becomes more complicated:

```
MyFunction(records, e => e.Id, e => e.Name?? e.Code)
MyFunction(records, e => e.Id, e => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Name)? e.Code : e.Name)
```

Are there other ways on how to process these without making too many parsers for each type of expression node?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do with those `Expression<>`... What do you do in `MyFunction`?

Comment: I have several functions that are similar to that one. But currently, I'm working on a generic method for generating a SelectList out of an IEnumerable/List while the 2nd parameter is for assigning which property will be used for the Value and 3rd parameter is for the display Text.

Comment: Why are you using `Expression<>`? You could simply pass two `Func<>`, then inside the `MyFunction(`: `foreach (var rec in records) { var id = val(rec); var text = text(rec); ... }`